# how to perform group by in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having this data in MongoDB, I want to perform group by on this data to get all the tracking numbers, under the same id in a single array format.

```
* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597056182a93692b4c7691bf"),
     "Sid":1,   
    "Carriers" : [ 
        {
            "Tracking" : [ 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "121_dom"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Tracking" : [ 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "779591314278"
                }, 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "779591314039"
                }, 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "779591314231"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597057338c65c002e4285fb3"),
    "Sid":2,    
    "Carriers" : [ 
        {
            "Tracking" : [ 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "122_dom"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Tracking" : [ 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "77959131427"
                }, 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "77959131403"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5980ae7ecc71b581b626d20b"),
     "Sid":3,     
    "Carriers" : [ 
        {
            "Tracking" : [ 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "123_dom"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Tracking" : [ 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "77959131408"
                }, 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "779591314059"
                }, 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "779591315551"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I.e  on performing group by operation on _id, which shows all tracking numbers under the same _Id in a single array, means the result set will be like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597056182a93692b4c7691bf"),
     "Sid":1,     
    "Carriers" : [ 
        {
            "Tracking" : [ 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "121_dom"
                }
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "779591314278"
                }, 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "779591314039"
                }, 
                {
                    "TrackingNo" : "779591314231"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: here is the query i had used 
db.getCollection('shipments').aggregate( { $project : {'Carriers.Tracking.TrackingNo':1}},{$unwind:'$Carriers'}).pretty();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to group nested arrays in one document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450119/mongodb-how-to-group-nested-arrays-in-one-document)

Answer (score 0):

As you have array within array, you first need to unwind twice and then group again. Following query should work. You need to project additional fields in $group and $project as required.

```
db.shipments.aggregate(
  {$unwind:'$Carriers'},
  {$unwind: '$Carriers.Tracking'},
  {$group: {_id:'$_id', c: {$push:  '$Carriers.Tracking'}}},
  {$project:{Carriers:  {Tracking: '$c'}}}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to description as mentioned in above question please try executing following aggregate query into MongoDB shell as a solution to above mentioned question.

```
db.shipments.aggregate(

// Pipeline
[
    // Stage 1
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$Carriers'
        }
    },

    // Stage 2
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$Carriers.Tracking'
        }
    },

    // Stage 3
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: '$_id',
                Sid: '$Sid'
            },
            Carriers: {
                $addToSet: {
                    TrackingNo: '$Carriers.Tracking.TrackingNo'
                }
            }

        }
    },

    // Stage 4
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            Carriers: {
                $addToSet: {
                    Tracking: '$Carriers'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // Stage 5
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$_id._id',
            Sid: '$_id.Sid',
            Carriers: '$Carriers'
        }
    }

]
```

);