# How to group by minimum value in nested arrays

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with unique user traits and I'm trying to combine it with their orders, produce a new collection with the first order date and sum the total of orders by the user.

Given this example collection:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "name" : "bob",
   "orders" : [ { "date" : "2019-01-01", "amount" : 10 }, { "date" : "2019-01-02", "amount" : 10 } ]
}
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "name" : "lisa",
   "orders" : [ { "date" : "2019-01-02", "amount" : 10 }, { "date" : "2019-01-03", "amount" : 15 } ]
}
```

this would be my desired output:

```
{
   "_id" : 1,
   "name" : "bob",
   "first_order" : "2019-01-01",
   "total_amount" : 20
}
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "name" : "lisa",
   "first_order" : "2019-01-02",
   "total_amount" : 25
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to group nested arrays in one document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46450119/mongodb-how-to-group-nested-arrays-in-one-document)

Comment: Try `db.collection.aggregate([ { '$project': { 'name': 1, 'first_order': { '$arrayElemAt': ['$orders', 0] }, 'total_amount': { '$sum': '$orders.amount' } } }])`, this assumes the `orders` array is ordered (no pun intended)